# Netbeans and Spring: two Java IDE on the same Windows system

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I'm a computer science student and I usually write my Java applications with NetBeans IDE, officially adopted by my school. Now I'm facing the possibility of a job, but the employer prefers Spring, as Java developing environment. I wonder if it's possibile for these two IDEs to run in the same Windows 10 system.
Thanks in Advance for your help.
Giuseppe Pala

Comment: it is not clear what you asking about

Answer (score 0):

Spring is not an IDE.  It is a Java framework.  You can definitely use them on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a framework. If you mean STS (spring tool suite) then no problem. You can use multiple IDE on the same system. You can even use multiple versions of the same IDE on the same system also.